# Serializing properties of collection?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I know every guideline says you should not inherit from list. I also realize there's not much sense in putting extra properties into such inherited type, instead they should be stored in the class which stores this collection internally. But imagine I absolutely have to.

Example of data structure:

```
public class Gen<TType> : List<TType>
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject<TType>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public Gen<TType> Items { get; set; }
}

var message = new RootObject<SomeClass>()
{
    X = 31,
    Items = new Gen<SomeClass>() { SomeValue = 22, Name = "name" }
};
```

Is there a way to serialize it without losing values of Gen<> specific properties (the "SomeValue" and "Name" ones)?

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json serializer.

Comment: "_s there a way to serialize it without losing values_" Yes, there is. Write a custom JsonConverter for your Gen<T> type and use it for both(!) serialization and deserialization.

Comment: also consider not deriving from `List<T>`.

Comment: @elgonzo, thanks, I'll try.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I would be glad not to do it, but what I have to do is to fix some existing legacy code which has this scenario for specific reasons.